# Do you want to open or save login.json from <IP>" popup comes in IE-10

Tags: java, jquery, html, json, jsp

**Do you want to open or save login.json from `<IP>`** popup comes in IE-10. while opening Java application over HTTPS connection ,and Login is blocked.

[image]

Notes:

1. observed this issue in IE10.
2. observed when accessing the application over HTTPS connection.

Comment: have you tried after resetting the settings to defaults?

Comment: Dear Jai,could you please elaborate this resetting in details, means how to do the same?

Comment: Dear Jai, I have done the resetting the IE setting to default, even after that problem comes